# Simulate Total Sales in R

Tags: r, simulation

I'm using R and I want to simulate different combinations of closed sales to predict the total sales for Q1 using the previous quarter's close rates for each of 18 different opportunity categories.  For each category I have a vector listing the dollar amounts for current open opportunities.

I don't want to simply multiply each opportunity value by the probability of closing that category of opportunity, which would give a single total predicted amount.  Rather I want to run multiple iterations of a simulation that will return either 0 or the listed dollar amount and then combine those values to calculate the total predicted sales for the quarter.  Then graph those simulations to show the likelihood that the sales department will hit a set goal.

I'm not sure if what I'm thinking even makes sense to try and do and would greatly appreciate some guidance on the code to make it happen.

The vectors I have for the various opportunity amounts and their corresponding probabilities are below.  Additionally, the vectors all vary in length from n=3 to n=393 if that matters.

```
APN  .13
ABN  .28
AFN  .79
APU  .47
ABU  .76
AFU  .95
EPN  .09
EBN  .52
EFN  .88
EPU  .42
EBU  .85
EFU  .95
NPN  .18
NBN  .73
NFN  .95
NPU  .47
NBU  .76
NFU  .95
```

Comment: To get started, take a look at `rbinom`. For example, to simulate 100 draws from `APN`, you could perform `rbinom(100, 1, 0.13)`. Also, it would help if we had the vector of returns (just 1 return for each symbol).

Comment: Thanks so much, that got me started and I was able to work it out from there!